# What material characteristics are most important for heating element material selection?

Tags: heat, conductivity, materials, resistivity

I want construct a heating element by screen printing a flat coil pattern of conductive paste onto an insulated substrate. This conductive paste consists of a powder of conductive metal contained in a viscous epoxy paste. There are several options for the type of conductive metal filler - so far I have found silver, carbon, graphite and nickel. What material characteristics should I be looking at in trying to assess the best filler material?
I want to make a heating element that will heat up quickly. The max temperature of the heating element will be 100 C.

I am thinking the two important qualities are Resistivity and Thermal Conductivity. Is there anything else I should take into account?

These are the specs on some pastes I have found. It seems like the Nickel paste would be best - is that right?

Nickel 
Volume Resistivity  <0.004 ohm. cm
Thermal Conductivity 1.44 W/M-K

Graphite
Volume Resistivity  0.004 ohm. cm
Thermal Conductivity 0.24 W/M-K

Silver
Volume Resistivity 3.00 E -3 ohm. cm
Thermal Conductivity 1.45 W/M-K

Carbon
Volume Resistivity  < 40 ohm. cm
Thermal Conductivity 0.25 W/M-K

Silver/Copper 
Volume Resistivity  3.70 E-2 ohm. cm
Thermal Conductivity 1.15 W/M-K

Comment: This definitely feels like a thermal and mechanical engineering problem. We have another [Engineering StackExchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com) that is more focused on any type of engineering.

Comment: Thanks KingDuken, I have posted the question to the  Engineering StackExchange. As per the guidelines of StackExchange though, I will not delete the question from here, as it has been answered.

Comment: Indeed, you can't delete the question anymore :) Oh well. But just for future reference, we do have that website for non-electrical engineering questions. You _may_ still ask electrical engineering questions on there too but I don't know what the criteria under which they would direct you over here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are others to take into account. Here are some (not necessarily an exhaustive list)

- Depending on what you mean by "quickly", heat capacity (both of the element and the substrate) may matter. This, combined with the available power, limit the rate of temperature change.
- Chemical stability in the intended environment may matter. This covers corrosion and combustibility.
- Toxicity may matter, especially if the application involves food or drink.
- Outgassing may matter in a vacuum environment (e.g. in orbit)
- Mechanical characteristics may matter if the element is subject to thermal shock, vibration, bending, etc.

There may be others : this is really too broad a question.